# Sympy could not subs the simple reconizable expressions

Tags: python, sympy

Consider the following code to reproduce the issue:

```py
from sympy import Function
eta = Function('eta')
from sympy import *

s,c,h=symbols('s c h',real=True)
sbar,cbar,hbar=symbols('sbar cbar hbar',real=True)

Number_of_derivatives=5

eta_dsymbol=[]
eta_ds=[]
eta_dsbar=[]

for ix in range(0,Number_of_derivatives+1):
    eta_ds.append(eta(s).diff(s,ix).subs(s,0))
    eta_dsbar.append(eta(sbar).diff(sbar,ix).subs(sbar,0))
    eta_dsymbol.append( Symbol("eta_d"+str(ix) , real=True) )
```

Now try replace Subs instances with a symbol:

```py
ix=1
Subs1 = eta_dsbar[ix]
Subs2 = eta_ds[ix]
sym = eta_dsymbol[ix]
eq = ( (eta(s).diff(s,1).subs(s,0)+1)**2*\
 (eta(sbar).diff(sbar,1).subs(sbar,0)+2)**3*\
 (eta(s).diff(s,1).subs(s,0)+eta(sbar).diff(sbar,1).subs(sbar,0)+5)**7 )\
.expand()
>>> eq.subs(Subs1, sym).subs(Subs2, sym)
128*eta_d1**12 + 3264*eta_d1**11 + 37920*eta_d1**10 + 265264*eta_d1**9 + 
1243704*eta_d1**8 + 4114644*eta_d1**7 + 9842070*eta_d1**6 + 17135025*eta_d1**5 + 
21528750*eta_d1**4 + 19015625*eta_d1**3 + 11193750*eta_d1**2 + 
3937500*Subs(Derivative(eta(s), s), s, 0) + 625000
>>> _.has(Subs)
True
```

Somehow the sympy package's subs function malfunctioned, and the subs of `Subs(Derivative(eta(s), s), s, 0)` were not recognized, even after the expand.
On the other hand, if I use a different symbol it does not appear:

```py
>>> A = Symbol("A")
>>> eq.subs(Subs1, sym).subs(Subs2, A).has(Subs)
False
>>> eq.subs(Subs1, A).subs(Subs2, sym).has(Subs)
False
```

What went wrong with the subs function?

Comment: print all terms in the subs.

Comment: @hpaulj Sorry, what did you mean? I used the .expand() already.

Comment: This problem has been fixed in the current version of SymPy which does not show the Subs.

Comment: @smichr Sorry, which version is it? I tried update in conda to '1.11.1' and it still showed up.(https://pypi.org/project/scipy/)

Comment: `>>> sympy.__version__ -> 1.13.dev'`